# Software for Managing Subscriptions to Website Content?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, subscription

Can you recommend a package that allows me to manage subscriptions to certain content on my website (not necessarily displayable) based on payment levels?

Ideally, the software would allow logging in using both site-specific registration *and* PayPal/Facebook/Twitter/MyOpenId, etc.

Preferably, it would also be open source, LAMP-based.

One idea that I have in mind is hacking a shopping cart software like Zen-Cart but this may be an overkill if a non-shopping lighter-weight package exists.

Comment: Does the site already exist? And if so, what software is it based on, if any? Most content management systems don't have subscription features built in, but do have several options available as plugins, for example.

Comment: @Su' No, the site doesn't exist yet. My understanding is that CMS are for *displayable* content but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "**Membership** software". You can find more information about the subject, along with a list of such packages in the Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membership_software